# How to plot multiple lists where items are either of string or int datatype

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matplotlib

Say i have the following 3 lists:

```
all_Ids = ["01", "02", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
all_xs = [12, 50, 36, 81, 70, 66, 34]
all_ys = [41, 50, 97, 22, 11, 89, 33]
```

Where the first contains node id's (some have to be of string datatype, while others have to be integers).

and the second and the third contain the x and y coordinates of each node respectively.

For example the 1st node has an id="01", x coord.=12 and y-coord="41, and so on.

I also have a list of lists, where each sublist corresponds to a closed route (a node permutation)

```
Routes = [["01", 2, 3, "01"], ["02", 1, "02"], ["01", 4, "01"], ["02", 5, "02"]]
```

I want to plot all routes in a single graph like this:
[image: Graph Example]

So far i have tried to convert the 3 lists to numpy arrays with np.array()

```
def SolutionPlot(xx, yy, all_ids, RoutesContainer):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(6, 6)
    allxs = np.array(xx) 
    allys = np.array(yy)
    for v in RoutesContainer:
        final_route = v
        final_route = np.array(final_route) 

        ax.plot(allxs[final_route], allys[final_route], ls="-", marker="o", markersize=8)

    plt.xlim([0, 100])
    plt.ylim([0, 100])
    plt.title("Vehicle Routing Problem (Clarke & Wright Heuristic)")

    for xi, yi, pidi in zip(xx, yy, all_ids):
        ax.annotate(str(pidi), xy=(xi,yi), fontsize = 13)

    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.set_size_inches(8, 8)
    
    plt.style.use('seaborn-dark-palette')  
    plt.show()
```

But when i call

```
SolutionPlot(allxs, allys, allIds, Routes)
```

I get the following IndexError:

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does error occur?  FULL TRACEBACK!`

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the x-axis values and the corresponding y-axis values
# for the first list.
x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

# Define the x-axis values and the corresponding y-axis values
# for the second list.
x2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
y2 = [3, 2, 1, 2, 3]

# Create a new figure.
plt.figure()

# Plot the first list.
plt.plot(x1, y1, '-o')

# Plot the second list.
plt.plot(x2, y2, '-o')

# Add a legend to the plot.
plt.legend(['First List', 'Second List'])

# Show the plot.
plt.show()
```